# Error in creating jsp file

Tags: jsp, struts

```
<%@taglib uri="http://jakarta.apache.org/struts/tags-html" prefix="html"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://jakarta.apache.org/struts/tags-bean" prefix="bean" %>
```

I'm creating jsp file in eclipse it shows error in  directive
it does not accept the uri which I mentioned above.

Comment: which version of struts are you using struts2 or earlier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from your question you used

**Struts Tag Libraries Automatic Configuration**

this is how it should be done

[Struts Tag Libraries Configuration automatic and manual](http://www.mkyong.com/struts/configure-the-struts-tag-libraries/)

This is the easy way, and used in Struts version 1.2, 1.3 and Servlet 2.3/2.4 container only. You do not need to define the “tlds” details in web.xml anymore, just include the struts-taglib.jar in your project classpath or copy it to WEB-INF/lib folder.

All the “tld” details are define inside the “struts-taglib.jar\META-INF\tld” folder. During deployment, the struts-bean.tld, struts-html.tld, struts-logic.tld and struts-tiles.tld will deploy automatically. However, you can access it via the following “pre-fixed uri” name only. In this method, you are not allow to change the “taglib uri” name.

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-bean" prefix="bean" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-html" prefix="html" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-logic" prefix="logic" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles" %>
```