# Even after adding struts jar i getting the error "org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page"

Tags: jakarta-ee, struts

I am trying to get user name and password input from UI and validating it in the form bean class.USing apache tomcat 6.0

```
<%@taglib uri="http://jakarta.apache.org/struts/tags-html" prefix="html"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://jakarta.apache.org/struts/tags-bean" prefix="bean" %>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Login page | Hello World Struts application in Eclipse</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <html:form action="login">
         <bean:message key="label.username" />
         <html:text property="userName"></html:text>
         <html:errors property="userName" />
         <br/>
         <bean:message key="label.password"/>
        <html:password property="password"></html:password>
         <html:errors property="password"/>
        <html:submit/>
        <html:reset/>
    </html:form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide complete stack trace. Which web or application server are you using?

Comment: Please provide stack trace because it's impossible to say without seeing it.

Comment: Unrelated, but how come you arbitrarily pick between using tag bodies and not, e.g., why don't you close all your tags the same way? Consistency is occasionally useful.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Struts 1.1 tags.

To use Struts 1.2,1.3 tags:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-bean" prefix="bean" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-html" prefix="html" %>
```

Possible Duplicate: [Error in creating jsp file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11077203/error-in-creating-jsp-file)
Ref: http://struts.apache.org/release/1.3.x/struts-taglib/index.html

To use Struts 2 tags:
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
Ref: http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/using-tags.html